# Is there a proper term for a "closed class hierarchy?"

Tags: object-oriented, class-design

What I mean by "closed class hierarchy" is a set of known base/derived classes used only for an implementation of something with no public API, i.e., the classes are not meant to be derived from by users. Another possible term might "non-extensible class hierarchy." But is there a proper term for this?

Comment: Sometimes, a class hierarchy that cannot be extended outside of the current module is called "sealed". [Kotlin has first-class support for `sealed class` hierarchies](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends who you ask.

Sealed (according to Kotlin) sounds like what you want.

> Sealed classes and interfaces represent restricted class hierarchies that provide more control over inheritance. All direct subclasses of a sealed class are known at compile time. No other subclasses may appear outside the module and package within which the sealed class is defined. For example, third-party clients can't extend your sealed class in their code. Thus, each instance of a sealed class has a type from a limited set that is known when this class is compiled.
>
> [kotlinlang.org - sealed-classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sealed-classes.html)

But sealed (according to C#) doesn't

> Sealed classes are used to restrict the users from inheriting the class. A class can be sealed by using the sealed keyword. The keyword tells the compiler that the class is sealed, and therefore, cannot be extended. No class can be derived from a sealed class.
>
> [geeksforgeeks.org - C# sealed class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-sealed-class/)

So be careful with this word. It means different things to different people.

[Java 17 adopted restricted class hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69218585/what-are-sealed-classes-in-java-17) by pairing the keywords `sealed` and `permits`. Seems Kotlin is not alone.

In Scala:

> Sealed classes are used for representing restricted class hierarchies. When a class is sealed, all subclasses must be declared in the same file. This feature allows pattern matching to be exhaustive, which will match all possible cases.
>
> [reintech.io - exploring pattern matching in scala](https://reintech.io/blog/exploring-pattern-matching-in-scala)

The more I read the more I think "restricted class hierarchies" is how you say this without getting mixed up with old keyword meanings.